# How many odd and convex functions exist in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

How many odd and convex functions $f: R^n \to R $ exist ?

I guessed just 1, namely $f(x)=\langle a, x \rangle $  where $a$ is a fixed $n-$vector.  But I couldn't either prove it or provide counter example.

Comment: Maybe like this: $f(x)$ convex $\Rightarrow$ $f(-x)$ convex $\Rightarrow$ $-f(x)$  convex and concave $\Rightarrow$ linear.

Comment: And use Theorem 2 from [this](https://pages.wustl.edu/files/pages/imce/nachbar/concavity.pdf).